# Why the Extension is "momd" but not "xcdatamodel" when search the path for the Model file

Tags: ios, core-data

I create a Master-Detail application using Core Data. And there is  a simple code to 
get the path for Model file:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

I have no idea why the extension isn't "xcdatamodel" but "momd".

Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 160):

The `mom` and `momd` files are compiled versions of `xcdatamodel` and `xcdatamodeld` files.

There information about how the compiling process works [here](http://www.warrenworks.com/ITP_137/References/CoreData.pdf) (page 31). To quote from the docs:

> A data model is a deployment resource. In addition to details of the entities and properties in the model, a model you create in Xcode contains information about the diagram—its layout, colors of elements, and so on. This latter information is not needed at runtime. The model file is compiled using the model compiler, `momc`, to remove the extraneous information and make runtime loading of the resource as efficient as possible.

Comment: @VIRGIL, you should accept this answer if it is correct for your question.

Comment: what does mom and momd stands for.

Comment: Interestingly, momd worked for me on my local machine but when uploaded to source and tested on a different machine it failed and required a change to mom. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: @khunshan "mom" stands for _managed object model_, and "momd" stands for _managed object model document_.

Comment: I've updated the link to a cached copy — Apple have restructured their Core Data documentation since I posted that answer.

Comment: @AmyWorrall Sorry but the link : http://warrenworks.com/ITP_137/References/CoreData.pdf does not exist now. I tried to find the exact quote in the archived document at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/ but did not find. Anyways the quote is enough to understand the concept. Thank you

Comment: Many times I found more information in comments than in the Answer. "mom" stands for managed object model, and "momd" stands for managed object model document." Loved This! :-)