# Xcode 8 Core Data Template for iOS 8,9

Tags: core-data, ios9, xcode8, ios10

I'm developing an app in a new Xcode 8 and I noticed an obvious thing. Xcode generated me Core Data with the latest API references. So if I change deployment target to iOS 8 or 9, it conflicts and propose me to take in brackets: `AVAILABLE` my Core Data code. That means I have to write from scratch Core Data code from previous API. Does anybody have template for AppDelegate with both of them or maybe it's possible to make Xcode generate them? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible in Xcode 8. But it's not hard to write your own code to set up the Core Data stack-- there's nothing magical about it, it's just code. Otherwise create a project with Xcode 7.3.1 (still available) and file a bug.

Answer (score 49):

Because no one should have to download Xcode 7, install it, start a new project, and port the template code to swift 3 just to utilize core data while still supporting iOS 8 & 9:

Swift 2 Core Data template methods from AppDelegate.swift:

```
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.cadiridris.coreDataTemplate" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("coreDataTemplate", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

Converted to swift 3:

```
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.cadiridris.coreDataTemplate" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "coreDataTemplate", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject?
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject?

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, when I made my project in xcode 8, the file extension for data model is "xcdatamodeld". Do i need to change that in code? or would momd work? Thanks

Comment: As further described in the link below: "The mom and momd files are compiled versions of xcdatamodel and xcdatamodeld files."

http://stackoverflow.com/a/10580677/3034715

You want to point it at the compiled version i.e. the mom/momd extension.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to [DCToDaylight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39814217/6872794). I made this file, which you can simply drag and drop. I have also made my managed object context static, and my init method private. So that someone can't accidentally instantiate a new context.

The function called `getContext` makes it easier every time you do something with core data.

The idea to create a static managedObjectContext, a separate file and the function came from [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=da6W7wDh0Dw&t=3064s).

For this example I made a new file called `DatabaseController.swift` and put all this code in there. This will simply make my code easier to manage and read. You can also copy from the `// MARK: - Core Data stack` to the bottom of the file and replace the similar code in you `AppDelegate.swift` and it will work.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class DatabaseController {

    private init() {

    }

    class func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        return DatabaseController.managedObjectContext
    }
    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    static var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {

        var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {
            // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.cadiridris.coreDataTemplate" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
            let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            return urls[urls.count-1]
        }()

        var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
            // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
            let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "YOUR_APP_NAME", withExtension: "momd")!
            return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
        }()

        var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
            // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
            // Create the coordinator and store
            let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)
            let url = applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
            var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
            do {
                try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
            } catch {
                // Report any error we got.
                var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
                dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject?
                dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject?

                dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
                let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
                // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }

            return coordinator
        }()

        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    class func saveContext () {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, for obvious reasons you cannot use the NSPersistantContainer, so you must use the Core Data Stack method by using the managedObjectContext.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick fix for that you just need to add an objective c class contains core data general function in order to get reference of NSManagedObjectContext and NSPersistentStoreCoordinator. (You can find code on SO or other site, Contact me in case you need that class.)

After adding the class use @Available 10 clause and in else part add code to take reference for aforementioned model.

Let me know if anyone found anything wrong with it.