# Is it possible to use core data (Xcode 8 and Swift 3.0) with both iOS 9 and 10 ?

Tags: core-data, ios9, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I want start new app in Swift 3 Xcode 8 and support iOS 8.4/9.x
How to deal with Core Data ?

Comment: Please give it a look, It might help someone in need. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44858661/6407986

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is easily possible. Swift 3 is targeted to run on iOS v8+. You will only be able to use the subset of APIs supported on iOS v8.4 though. The best way to find out the answer to your question though is to create a test project that uses Core Data. You'll find that `NSPersistentContainer` creates an error. Why? It isn't available on the earlier OSes. Alternatively, create a test project with Xcode 7 and then migrate it to Swift 3, you'll see that it can easily work every where.

Comment: Just note that you can't submit an app from Xcode 8 until Xcode 8 is released, and if you've built your app with Xcode 8 it won't build in Xcode 7.x (at least if you use Interface Builder at all).

Answer (score 11):

For anyone looking for it, I added the core data template generated by xcode 7 (swift 2) and its swift 3 conversion in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39814217/3034715

Comment: Thanks, saved my day.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been searching for this! :)