# value of type AppDelegate has no member managedObjectContext

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode8, managedobjectcontext

## Code

```
    let managedObjectContext =
        (UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate
            as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

## Error:

- Value of type `AppDelegate` has no member `managedObjectContext`,

My problem is I want to use `managedObjectContext` in Xcode 8, but it says `AppDelegate` have no such member. I want to use this because i want to create a project for ios 9 with core data.
I want the definition of `managedObjectContext`,please comment if you have

Comment: when you created the project have you checked `use core data` ? or it was unchecked ?

Comment: I think you need to refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032818/adding-core-data-to-existing-iphone-project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032818/adding-core-data-to-existing-iphone-project)

Comment: yes i checked it,the problem is i am creating a project for ios 9, and xcode 8 is creating appdelegate file with core data compatible with ios 10.

Comment: it adds persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer which is not compatible with ios 9

Comment: There's an answer on SO that includes class source for the older style of Core Data access, but converted to Swift 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120937/xcode-8-core-data-template-for-ios-8-9/39814217#39814217

Comment: then [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140188/is-it-possible-to-use-core-data-xcode-8-and-swift-3-0-with-both-ios-9-and-10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140188/is-it-possible-to-use-core-data-xcode-8-and-swift-3-0-with-both-ios-9-and-10) this one may help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer,may be it will work , but i want to know where i will put the name of my ".xcdatamodelId" in managedObjectContext to make connection with my data model.

Answer (score -1):

## Explanation:

- Error is quite clear, it states that `AppDelegate` doesn't have a property called `managedObjectContext`. Check `AppDelegate` and see if a property with the name `managedObjectContext` exists.

## Reference:

It is very important to learn the following before writing code:

- Concepts - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/coreDataOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010398-CH28-SW1
- Step by step guide - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1

Comment: i understand the error but i want the definition of managedObjectContext which i found now.

Comment: Refer to the 1st link, it is time consuming to read but will help you understand clearly. ManagedObjectContext is like a scratch pad where you can make changes. Then later you can save the context.

Answer (score -1):

**You need to just create a project with tick mark of "Use Core Data"** and it will available in app delegate of you project.[image of project creation and selection of use core data tick mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq1f1.png)

```
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "temp")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

**Use in app delegate**

```
let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
```

Comment: The question says, "i want to create a project for ios 9".  Did you try your solution on iOS 9?

Comment: yes i want to create project for ios 9,so i want "appdelegate.swift" file with core data checked.If anyone having file for ios 9, please refer.

Comment: Phillip Mills Can you help please,Thanks

Comment: @VikrantSingh - There's a link in the comments on your question to another question which has the best answer I can give you.