# swift 3 : present does not work on iOS 9 and older

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I'm trying to present a UIImagePickerController and when I use:

```
self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I get this error:

```
'NSPersistentContainer' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer
```

I want my app to support iOS 8 and later

Edit : 
The picker code :

```
  if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {
        var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: put some code about where u use the `NSPersistentContainer`

Comment: @ronan I didn't use it but when I call present() to present a new viewController I get the error  , so I guess present does use the NSPersistentContainer , and I don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: Your question makes little sense. `NSPersistentContainer` is a new Core Data class. It has nothing to do with presenting a view controller. The first thing you need to do, if you wish to support iOS 9 or earlier with your Core Data app is to remove uses of `NSPersistentContainer` and go back to older Core Data code.

Comment: @rmaddy is right. `NSPersistentContainer` has nothing to do with `present` method. I think the problem lies in you `picker`, what's that. can you put code about the picker?

Comment: @ronan I just posted the picker's code

Comment: When does this crash happen? Is it when you present the picker or when you click the choose/cancel button in the PhotoLibrary?

Comment: The code doesn't compile at all , I found a solution but I need to test it on iOS  9 or older to make sure it works , the solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120937/xcode-8-core-data-template-for-ios-8-9/39814217#39814217

Answer (score 0):

According to apple docs:https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nspersistentcontainer

We can see on the right side:

> SDKs
>
> iOS 10.0+
>      macOS 10.12+
>      tvOS 10.0+
>      watchOS 3.0+

Means if you develop iOS,`NSPersistentContainer` is only can use in iOS 10.0 or newer version. You can not use in iOS 8, or lower than iOS 10

Comment: yes I understand that but how can I present the view controller? , when I use presentViewController I get an error which tells me that the function was renamed to present , and when I call present I get the error

Comment: @melos Which ios version simulator are you using? choose the iOS 10 simulator.

Comment: the error is not because of the simulator it's because of the deployment target which is in my case iOS 8.0 , Plus I tries to run it on my device which is 10.1 and I get the same error

Comment: @melos So, if you just want to test the `NSPersistentContainer `, you should set `TarARGET` -> `General` -> `Development Info` -> `Development Target` to `iOS 10` or more higher, attention, this just for test , if you want to support ` ios 8`, you must replace the `NSPersistentContainer`.