# Core Data: bundle.main.url Thread 1 fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, error-handling

I've been fighting with this error for an hour now, I can't see what's wrong here...

[image]
[image]

I checked `target` and duplicate files

Comment: I do not see a file called `CryptoGODM.momd`.

Comment: @luk2302 it doesn't work with `xcdatamodeld` either..

Comment: Try looking into AppDelegate. If you checked the option with CoreData while creating this project you should see something like this: NSPersistentContainer(name: "SomeName") in your AppDelegate.

Comment: @Phyber Thanks Phyber, forgot to check that but it is `NSPersistentContainer(name: "CryptoGODM")`

Comment: Please don't post images of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the screenshots, I suppose the name of the storage should be: CryptoGO. Try this:

```
guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "CryptoGO", withExtension: "momd") else {
    fatalError("Unable to Find Data Model")
}
```

Comment: It works! :) How did you know that looking at the screenshots??

Comment: Yeah, I just edited it back to the initial answer. Looking at the screenshot I saw the name of your project: "CryptoGO" and usually project name and the name of the storage is the same.

Comment: So that means the `. xcdatamodeld` file has nothing to do here?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579767/why-the-extension-is-momd-but-not-xcdatamodel-when-search-the-path-for-the-m) and also [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html).

Answer (score -1):

You don't have a file "CryptoGODM.momd", as you set in your

```
Bundle().url(forResource: "CryptoGODM", withExtension: "momd")
```

Your file has the extension ".xcdatamodeld".

Comment: It doesn't work with `withExtension: xcdatamodeld` unfortunately

Comment: Could you post your directory structure? Perhaps CryptoGODM.xcdatamodeld is in an subdirectory. In this case you also need to call with the name of the subdirectory. API doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1416712-url

Comment: I updated the screenshots in my question, `CryptoGODM.xcdatamodeld` is actually in the main folder